# Running project in console

Tags: postgresql, grails, intellij-idea

so I have this kind of big grails project connected to my postgresql.I found the file which contains the main class and executed it as a main file,however I got around 100 warnings most of them concerning XML things and 1 error which was GC memory error,so I was wondering how can I fix that?I am using intelliJ as IDE

Comment: grails version? what do the warnings look like? With the scant information you provided, about all anyone can say is "Fix the unknown warnings and the GC memory error, and it should run fine." StackOverflow people aren't mind readers...

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about idea and haven't worked with grails 3.x so far...

But I'm a bit confused about your statement:

```
I found the file which contains the main class and executed it as a main file
```

usually, I run and test an application through the command

```
grails run-app
```

in the application folder or via deploying the created war file to a servlet-container...